# Array modified via two others in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have three 1-D arrays:

- A (say of length 5),
- B (the same length, 5 in the example)
- C (much longer, say of length 100)

`C` is initially filled with zeros. `A` gives indices of `C` elements which should be changed (they may repeat), and `B` gives values which should be added to initial zeros of `C`. For example, if `A = [1, 3, 3, 3, 29]` and `B = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3]`, `C[1]` should become 2, `C[3] - 9`, `C[29] - 3`; all other `C` elements should remain 0.
I've written it as a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + B[i]
```

But is there a more efficient way to do the same in `numpy` in the vector form?

Comment: I don't think you mean `len(A)-1`; that will skip the last element (29 & 3), as `range` doesn't include the upper bound.  `range(3) == [0,1,2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be able to use `bincount`, at least for the 1-D case:

```
>>> A = np.array([1,3,3,3,29])
>>> B = np.array([2,3,4,2,3])
>>> np.bincount(A, B)
array([ 0.,  2.,  0.,  9.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  3.])
```

(Aside: duplicated values when using `numpy` indexing can behave very strangely, and it's very easy to be led astray by the behaviour you see in simple cases.  I avoid them entirely, as the behaviour is almost never what I want.)